# Angular stepper ng template method call infinity

Tags: angular, stepper

I have an application that contains a stepper and each step is represented by a subcomponent

```
  <app-stepper #stepper>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let step of listeEtapes; let i = index; trackBy: trackStep;">
      <cdk-step aria-labelledby="{{step}}" label="{{getLibelleEtapeByCode(step)}}">
        <div class="step-container">
          <div class="box-content">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplateRefByStepCode(step!)!"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext] ="{indexStep:i}">
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </div>
      </cdk-step>
    </ng-container>
  </app-stepper>

  <ng-template #ETAPE1 let-indexStep="indexStep">
    <app-etape1 *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === indexStep"
      [personne]="getPersonne()"
      [ordre]="getOrdre(indexStep)"
    >
    </app-etape1>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #ETAPE2 let-indexStep="indexStep">
    <app-etape1 *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === indexStep"
      [personne]="getPersonne()"
      [ordre]="getOrdre(indexStep)"
    >
    </app-etape1>
  </ng-template>
```

Ces étapes prennent des paramètre en entrée que je récupère via des méthode. Exemple :

```
getPersonne(){
         console.log(this.personneService.getAllPersonne());

         return this.personneService.getDetailPersonneById(1);
}
```

My problem is that my methods are called indefinitely as soon as I am on the stage in question. As soon as I move the mouse or do an action they are called

Comment: Create a functional example in stackblitz for us.